# Attempt to reboot remote system after installation using python2.7

Tags: python

I am new to python(2.7) and trying to help my organization in some project work where remote server(CentOS7) need to be verified and performed certain actions
on some criteria.
Post update and installation on server, I want to perform clean reboot, but sometime I have observed the reboot itself get stuck.

**This is what I have**

```
if uptime_seconds < 1000: 
    uptime_string = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=uptime_seconds)) #Convert time into sec
    do_log("Last reboot attempt was %s ago" % uptime_string)
 else:
    do_log("Attempting to reboot the system")
    process=subprocess.Popen(['timeout' ,'120', 'reboot'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #timeout the reboot if in 120 seconds
```

**This is what I want:**

Along with above code If clean reboot takes more than 120s then sysrq should be triggered for hard reboot
If above condition does not meet, then below script should be executed

```
if uptime_seconds < 1000: 
      uptime_string = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=uptime_seconds)) #Convert time into sec
      do_log("Last reboot attempt was %s ago" % uptime_string)
elif:
      do_log("Attempting to reboot the system")
      process=subprocess.Popen(['timeout' ,'120', 'reboot'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #timeout the reboot if in 120 seconds
else:
      os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq && echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger') # send sysrq for hard reboot.
```

Also, I am not able to store any output from **process** variable(from above script) or get the any returncode value as it immediately triggers the reboot command. Is there anyway I can put some condition on reboot timeout? It's hard to test even this scenario as I can't reach to the second condition, not able to resist from reboot.

Comment: Linux is not Windows and rarely requires a reboot after an installation.

Comment: @KlausD.Mine In my case it does require as client software needed, for their own software maintenance and application upgrade.

Comment: Once reboot command is given, all processes are stopped then the machine is rebooted. You will have no control over your program anymore. So no, this is not possible. What do u mean by the reboot getting stuck?

Comment: @leoOrionAfter reboot execution system hungs and someone from on-premise has to hard reboot it.

Comment: Can you check syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) after this stuck situation? This is not a natural situation so taking a look at logs would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this:
If clean reboot doesn't happen in 120s, do hard reboot.

```
reboot_chk = subprocess.Popen(['timeout' ,'120', 'reboot'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            output, error = reboot_chk.communicate()
            print(output)
            if reboot_chk.returncode != 0:
                print("Attempting to hard reboot the system")
                os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq && echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger') # send sysrq for hard reboot.
```